# Manage service application list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I need to add User Profile Service and Managed Metadata Service to develop sharepoint app, but **New** button contain only three services. Is any way to extend it ?
http://puu.sh/pk49e/e442fe812e.png

Answer (score 1):

User Profile Service and Managed Metadata Service are not available in SharePoint Foundation. You will need to upgrade to SharePoint Server.